# How can I add a descriptive string to assert

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to see some meaningful description at assertion failure.

Here is my code and its execution:

```
>cat /tmp/1.py
a="aaa" + "bbb"
print(a)
assert ("hello" + a) and 0

>python /tmp/1.py
aaabbb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1.py", line 3, in <module>
    assert ("hello" + a) and 0
AssertionError
```

I am using Python 3.7.

You know why `"hello" + a` is not evaluated first as a string concatenation? And how can I make it?

[**UPDATE**] Thanks for all the replies, here is what I am looking for:

```
>cat /tmp/1.py
a="aaa" + "bbb"
print(a)
assert 0, "hello" + a
```

Comment: `assert` [accepts an expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert), so it checks the entire `("hello" + a) and 0`.

Comment: I really like how your using the shell to describe a problem with python :)

Comment: `assert 0`? You know what will always fail, right?

Answer (score 6):

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), the failure message follows a comma:

```
assert some_condition, "This is the assert failure message".
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if __debug__:
    if not some_condition:
        raise AssertionError("This is the assert failure message")
```

And as noted in the comments, `assert` is not a function call. Don't add parenthesis, or you may have odd results. `assert(condition, message)` will be interpreted as a tuple being used as a condition with no message, and will never fail.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that you definitely shouldn't pretend that assert is a function call.  A statement like `assert(condition, message)` will never fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your description just after your `assert` statement with a comma.

Such as:

```
assert ("hello" + a) and 0, 'Your description'
```

The result will be:

```
aaabbb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    assert ("hello" + a) and 0, "Your description"
AssertionError: Your description
```